# Using Filter Method to Remove Item from Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, events

I am new to React and I am trying to build a very basic timesheet tool, where users can add tasks into the application and save. I am using React as well as Typescript.

So far I have my main component that includes an empty array of tasks and the table. Then inside the table body I have mapped to pull the table rows and a separate component that includes the tags.

I am trying to add in a button to delete tasks using the filter method on the array to remove the index for the individual item, however nothing happens when I click, or I get an undefined error. Can someone please help? I am using the delete button and handle delete function below to achieve this

Main Component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ITimesheetToolProps } from './ITimesheetToolProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import TableRow from './TableRow';
import styles from './TimesheetTool.module.scss';

export default class TimesheetTool extends React.Component<ITimesheetToolProps, any> {
  state = {
    tasks: []
  }

  addTask = (task) => {
    const tasks = [...this.state.tasks];
    this.setState({tasks: this.state.tasks.concat(task)});
  }

  handleDelete = (index) => {
    const tasks = this.state.tasks.filter(t => t.index !== index);
    this.setState({ tasks });
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<ITimesheetToolProps, any> {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={(task) => this.addTask(task)}>Add Task</button>
        <table>
          <thead className={styles.tbody}>
            <tr>
              <th>Project</th>
              <th>Task</th>
              <th>Monday</th>
              <th>Tuesday</th>
              <th>Wednesday</th>
              <th>Thursday</th>
              <th>Friday</th>
              <th>Saaturday</th>
              <th>Sunday</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody className={styles.tbody}>
            {this.state.tasks.map((task, index) => <tr key={index}><TableRow /><td><button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(index)}>Delete</button></td></tr>)}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to help without knowing the shape of the data, but i think this is what you're looking for, help me know if this helps

```
const tasks = this.state.tasks.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
```

The code works, why it is removing the last item in the array i don't know, you'll have to

```
//change <button onClick..../>
// to this.
<button onClick={handleDelete(index)}/>

//change handleDelete to this..
const handleDelete = (index) => () => this.setState({tasks: this.state.tasks.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped and it is now removing items, but it is removing the last item from the array. I want to remove the item that is clicked. Could you also explain what this is doing inside the filter method? ie what is the underscore for? Also, what do you mean by 'shape of the data?

Comment: filter is a "higher order function" which means it takes another function is a parameter. The function you pass as a parameter is run over every item, if the function returns true it keeps the item; if it returns false it removes the item.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still just deleting the last item

Answer (score 0):

Use Splice.

```
 handleDelete = (index) => { 
    this.setState({ tasks: this.state.tasks.splice(index,1);
 });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this just deletes all items apart from the first one